# Browser client takes a long time to make a POST request to server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

When I try posting a form to my Node.js server, a browser client (Chrome in my case) takes forever (~2 minutes) to send the response and receive the HTML it's supposed to render. When I make the same post request using Postman, it happens instantly.

When I try sending the data through a browser, THEN send it through Postman (while the browser is still loading its POST request), my browser will also render the HTML. If I don't send a request in Postman also and just let it load, the browser will continue to have a loading spinner in the favicon until it displays a ERR_EMPTY_RESPOSNE message.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
```

Node.js:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("post received");
  res.render('songs');
})
```

Comment: If the postman renders instantly than the problem is not on the backend, you should focus on the front end part, can you put the login.js code also the headers which are you sending to the back in the question it can light us.

Answer (score 0):

2 min, is a specific timeout of a Node.js server, if a client makes a request two the server, but won't get any response from the server in two minutes, it's 99% 
the server problem. I can tell what your problem really is since you provided very little code here, but I can give you some idea why such a problem occurs.

In my experience, some guy just had such a problem of timeout, he mistakenly set the `res` object to the outside scope of an express callback, and though he could call that `res` later to send data to the client. This is a big mistake. `req` and `res` can only be called in a middleware or router, if assigned to an out-scope variable, its status will be change, because any request can change and will change the variable, and the current request won't get any response since the outside variable has been modified before sending any data.

And another situation is, when you define a middleware, you forget to call `next()`, it's just a very simple mistake that makes you want to cry.

If none of this situations is yours, perhaps you could put more code here, and let's see what real problem it might be.